# How can I get xlim, ylim values of figure in python?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I am using figure module in a python project. In this project there are more than one figure plots. I want to get zoom ratio and zoom position of user and implement them in to other figures. In other words I want all figures have same zoom conditions.

Edit (More clearer version):
How can I get xlim, ylim values of figure?

Comment: Your question is not terribly clear. Can you show us your code, and maybe some examples of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 6):

xlim and ylim are properties of `Axes` not `Figure`. You can get it by:

```
ax.get_xlim()
ax.get_ylim()
```

to monitor changes:

```
ax.callbacks.connect("xlim_changed", func)
ax.callbacks.connect("ylim_changed", func)
```

where `func()` is your function to calculate the zoom and pan.